# Google Assistant is not opening my Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, shortcut, google-assistant

Google Assistant is not opening my Flutter app when I call "Hey Google, open MyAppName". I tested it with another application that I have made in IONIC and it worked normally. And here [https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/overview#:~:text=Launch%20it%20by%20telling%20Assistant,integration%20work%20required%20from%20you](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/overview#:%7E:text=Launch%20it%20by%20telling%20Assistant,integration%20work%20required%20from%20you) they say you don't need to do it no additional implementation for the app to launch. Does anyone have any ideas, I need this to work. I also can't get App Actions to work with Flutter

I tried to configure an App Action using shortcuts to open a specific feature of the app following this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions-2?hl=pt-br#0

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.